# Azure Data Factory development with multiple users

Tags: azure-data-factory

can any one help me  how to lock pipeline in ADF, is there any option when one developer is working other should not work, as with multiple developers are working on same pipeline  without using Source Control

Comment: The only thing that makes is sense to actually use source control.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there is no feature in Azure portal for Azure data factory to lock the pipeline changes if 2 or more are working on the same pipeline. You would have to create a clone of existing pipeline and work on those clones else the best way is to use source control like git